# Chain length when upgrading chain ring

Tags: chain, chainring, 1x11

I currently run a 1x11 with a 30t chain ring. I'm upgrading to a 32t chain ring and a new chain. The cassette will be the same. Would I be correct in assuming I need to be +2 links on my new chain?

Comment: Roughly.  The "proper" way to answer this is to size a new chain to the combo.

Answer (score 4):

No, you need +1 link on your new chain because the chain only contacts about half the chain ring so you go from 15 links around it to 16.  You need to add links 2 at a time because you need one inner and one outer.  You can either use the same length chain you have, which will bring the derailleur forward to give up 1 link or add 2 links and ask the derailleur to move aft to take up 1 link.  It depends which end of the derailleur travel you are closer to the end of.  If you care, the 2 links weigh about 4 grams.  See [this answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/79334/how-much-to-shorten-chain-when-changing-36t-to-28t-chainring?rq=1) also.

Comment: Most folks seem to prefer the use of a quick link to join their chains which require the chain to be cut resulting in inner links on each end of the trimmed chain. Even 11s Shimano chains are provided with their version of a quick link although it is common to find 8-10s Shimano chains joined by a 3rd party's quick link as opposed to the Shimano preferred reinforced connecting pin.  Use of a connecting pin requires the chain cut to result in one inner and one outer link.   Since a new chain is going on, it may be best and less speculative to size it by the big-big wrap +2 links method.